# Can't see content on page to edit

Tags: pages

complete noob here, so please bear with me. I'm trying to edit a page in wordpress made by a coworker who's on vacation, but I don't see anywhere on the page where I can edit code or use the visual editor.

The only prompt I receive is:

Calendar 
Start writing with text or HTML

It's even more weird because I can see the page in preview mode, but in the editor there's nothing but the message above. I attached a screenshot of the editor page and the preview page. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

[image: Visual Editor]

[image: Preview Page]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information. Are you trying to make an edit to the page that displays events, or one of the events itself? If you're trying to edit the Events they should have their own Custom Post Type in the sidebar of the dashboard.